# Passing data between controllers with a service not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a service for passing data between two controllers, but something isn't working proper.

This is the service:

```
app.factory('SubmitService', function($rootScope) {
    var data = {};

    data.prepForBroadcast = function(recvData) {
        data = recvData;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    data.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return data;
});
```

It isn't very complicated, it just has to pass an object between controllers. These are the functions that handle this service in my controllers:

In the sending controller (from a form):

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    submitService.prepForBroadcast($scope.formData);
}
```

In the receiving controller (which controls a list of items):

```
$scope.$on('SubmitService', function() {
    this.pruebaNota.push(submitService.data);
});
```

I call the submit function from a button, simply on an onClick:

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary" style="height:35px;width:100px;float:right;"  id="submit"
    ng-disabled="isDisabled()" ng-click="submit()">
    Enviar
    </button>
```

---

EDIT 2: This is my receiving controller and a part of it's test array:

```
    app.controller('noteController', ['$scope', 'SubmitService', function($scope, submitService) {

        $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
            this.pruebaNota.push(submitService.data);
        });


    this.pruebaNota = [{
        "titulo":"Una nota de prueba",
        "texto":"Un texto de prueba para ver qué tal funciona esto. Ejemplo ejemplo ejemplo!!!",
        "fecha": new Date()
    },
// more examples that aren't interesting at all
```

I guess I'm having a trouble accessing my array, but which is the actual problem? I'm still a little novice at JS.

Comment: first of all,change `onClick` with `ng-click` directive

Comment: there's lots of issues there else... in factory `data` is declared as `var` but later referenced via `this`..

Comment: Changed both things. Let me edit the post.

Comment: well, now the question is whether it was a typo when making the post or is this the issue in real code?

Comment: answer to your new edited question: yes it will show that

Comment: well, not sure what is should show... The event listener is subscribed to a a wrong event. `$scope.$on('SubmitService'` should listen to `handleBroadcast` and not to a service name

Comment: Thank you, that was an issue! Now the problem is that I'm trying to store the object in an array that I defined this.array inside the controller, and it's telling me that this.array is not defined. I guess that's because the reference "this" is calling the function, instead of the controller... how can I solve this? How can I define my array with the typical "var" and being able to access it?

Comment: in order to help you, Can you please show us your controller?

Comment: If you are trying to access `pruebaNota` in the view, You should replace `this` with `$scope` or use `Controller As`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it work for array modification, reference proper object in event handler.

```
var self = this;
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    self.pruebaNota.push(submitService.data);
});
```

**Note:** You've got a rather messy factory. It works it's the weirdest notation I've seen.

```
app.factory('SubmitService', function($rootScope) {
    //ok: define a variable that will be returned and later injected into controllers
    var data = {};

   //ok: add functions to the object being returned
    data.prepForBroadcast = function(recvData) {
  //not evident: replace the variable accessible in closure with a new object
  //if you try to modify existing data here instead of reassignment
  //it will ruin the service injected to controllers
        data = recvData;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };
   ...
    return data;
});
```

Comment: The top code worked! Now it's adding an object into the array, but something's wrong here... the new item has no info, it gets added but without any values. Both objects have the same structure: "titulo", "texto", "fecha", but they are not being passed properly I guess.

Comment: please reproduce the issue in fiddle or plunker

Comment: Fixed! Didn't understand at first glance ur second part, but now I did. I added a new variable to the data object in which I binded the data, so now it worked perfectly! Thank you :) !